# Very low specificity in random forests classification model with balanced classes

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, sensitivity-specificity

I've been building a model within a k-fold cross-validation,and seem to be getting pretty much the same results i.e. very high sensitivity and low specificity.

What I've tried:

- Different values of k for the cv
- Different numbers of trees built
- Less features, selecting ones I know from clinical experience tend to be important

However, it ends up being pretty much the same results, an example of which is below.
[image: confusion matrix]

Do you have any suggestions as to what might improve the specificity? Would e.g. dimensionality reduction or a different kind of model perform better for this kind of data (one continuous variable, the rest binary categorical)?

Comment: Your random forest returns a predicted probability; you could always increase specificity (while decreasing sensitivity) by increasing the threshold required for "Test +" from 0.5 to some larger value (e.g. 0.7 or 0.8). Does this answer your question, or are you looking for general tips to increasing specificity without changing sensitivity?

Comment: Thank you - I will try that! I think I'm willing to sacrifice some sensitivity (maybe down to 80-85% or so) if it brings up specificity enough. In case it doesn't, do you have any general tips?

Comment: Unfortunately improving one without harming the other requires a better model fit. Without know more about your data it would be hard to make suggestions that are too concrete; one obvious (and easy) approach would be trying a few other types of models (e.g. xgboost) and seeing if any fit better.

Comment: You can look into plotting an ROC curve, which shows every achievable sensitivity and specificity by moving the positivity threshold. This would enable you to easily (and visually) see if there are any thresholds that simultaneously give you a high sensitivity and specificity.